# What is the usage of tilde symbol (~) in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle10g

What is the usage of tilde symbol (~) in Oracle.
Please share me the output for the below query if we are using the column name and table name with two tilde symbols.

**SELECT ~column_name~ from ~Table_name~**

Comment: There is none, probably you've seen it as a notation for a placeholder. And you can check the output yourself, there is always http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 1):

From the [Database Object Names and Qualifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223) documentation:

> 6. Nonquoted identifiers must begin with an alphabetic character from your database character set. Quoted identifiers can begin with any character.
> 7. Nonquoted identifiers can contain only alphanumeric characters from your database character set and the underscore (`_`), dollar sign (`$`), and pound sign (`#`). Database links can also contain periods (`.`) and "at" signs (`@`). Oracle strongly discourages you from using `$` and `#` in nonquoted identifiers.
>
>    Quoted identifiers can contain any characters and punctuations marks as well as spaces. However, neither quoted nor nonquoted identifiers can contain double quotation marks or the null character (`\0`).

In the query:

```sql
SELECT ~column_name~ from ~Table_name~
```

`~column_name~` and `~Table_name~` are non-quoted identifiers as they are not surrounded by double-quotes `"`. However, since they do not start with an alphabetic character and they contain `~` characters (which are not alpha-numeric, `_`, `$` or `#`) then the identifiers are invalid and the query will raise an exception, outputting:

> ```
> ORA-00911: invalid character
> ```

and will not execute.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vZhv-pK8)

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer the title of your question, tilde is rarely used as a PL/SQL not equals operator:

```
begin
    if 1 ~= 2 then
        dbms_output.put_line('Not equal');
    end if;
end;
/
```

As far as I know, that is the only valid use of tilde in Oracle, and as MTO explained, it certainly can't be used for object names without double quotes.